# Ajax Control Toolkit fails to load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am having trouble getting my AJAX control tool kit working in asp.net.  The website runs fine when I run it using the `localhost/website.aspx` address however when I attempt to access the website via the net I get the error below.  Any Suggestions?

> Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly
>   'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
>   find the file specified.

```
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" 
CodeFile="Submit_Employee_Info.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" 
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>

Line 3:  <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" 
 Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

Source File: /RequestForm/Submit_Employee_Info.aspx    Line: 3

Comment: I dragged and dropped the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll into the assembly folder and now the page will load, however none of the calender extenders work now! Any Ideas?

Comment: Not sure exactly what was wrong however when I upgraded my site to .net 4.5 as well as the IIS settings in addition to repairing my .net 4.5 installation it finally started working even though it is the .net 3.5 version of Toolkit

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not much reputations so posting as answer instead of comments. Do you have ajax toolkit dll referenced in your project. To confirm, check your bin/debug director.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your local solution, expand the `references` folder in the web application, and find the `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`.
2. Right click, Properties, and check the path to where the DLL is referenced
3. If it's referenced to a folder outside of your project, you will need to include this in the project.

You have a couple of choices...

1. Copy DLL into a `3rdPartyLibs` folder in the solution, and change the reference to point here
2. Use [`Nuget`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/AjaxControlToolkit/) to download the file into the solution, the only issue here is that the version may be incorrect, so option 1 here might be best in your scenario.

Comment: I was able to update the reference however the same error is still occuring